# Scala polymorphism for type casting

Tags: scala

I have some methods like:

```
  def floatValueOrNone(value: String): Option[Float] = {
    if (!value.equals("NA")) Option(value.toFloat) else None
  }

  def intValueOrNone(value: String): Option[Int] = {
    if (!value.equals("NA")) Option(value.toInt) else None
  }

  def stringValueOrNone(value: String): Option[String] = {
    if (!value.equals("NA")) Option(value.toString) else None
  }
```

I'd like to use one method for all of these, but types can't be stored in a variable so I was wondering if there is a small clean way to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722990/scala-convert-string-to-generic-type

Comment: Also google 'scala fromstring'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit conversions to the rescue:

```
def valueOrNone[T](value: String)(implicit conv: String => T): Option[T] = {
  if (!value.equals("NA")) Option(conv(value)) else None
}
```

This will work for all cases you stated. If you want to convert to some non-standard type that doesn't have a default implicit conversion in scope, then make sure to provide one:

```
class MyCustomClass(str: String) { 
  override def toString = "my custom class: " + str
}

implicit def fromString(str: String) = new MyCustomClass(str)

println(valueOrNone[MyCustomClass]("foo")) // prints "my custom class: foo"
```

Comment: I had to add `implicit def strToFloat(str: String) = str.toFloat` to get `valueOrNone[Float]("0.4")` working.

Comment: I think this is a really bad idea, but if you're set on it, you should provide an explicit return type for `fromString`—see e.g. [Programming Scala](https://books.google.com/books?id=AnurBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA157&ots=7K9An7t9XU&dq=%22always%20specify%20the%20return%20type%20of%20an%20implicit%20conversion%20method%20%22&pg=PA158#v=onepage&q=%22always%20specify%20the%20return%20type%20of%20an%20implicit%20conversion%20method%20%22&f=false): "Always specify the return type of an implicit conversion method…".

Comment: Ah sorry yes, I overlooked that you had a Float. If you said only `valueOrNone("0.4")` then it would work since it would use the conversion to Double. But as I said, for those that don't have a default conversion available you can add your own (which you did).

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend not using implicit conversions here. Implicit conversions make your code more difficult to reason about and maintain, slow down compilation time (this isn't often a concern, but when it is, it can be really bad), and require a special feature flag in recent Scala versions.

Instead you can use a custom type class, which I'll call `Read`:

```
trait Read[A] { def apply(s: String): Option[A] }

object Read {
  def instance[A](parse: String => A): Read[A] = new Read[A] {
    def apply(s: String): Option[A] = if (s != "NA") Option(parse(s)) else None
  }

  implicit val floatRead: Read[Float] = instance(_.toFloat)
  implicit val intRead: Read[Int] = instance(_.toInt)
  implicit val stringRead: Read[String] = instance(identity)

  def valueOrNone[A](s: String)(implicit read: Read[A]): Option[A] = read(s)
}
```

And then:

```
scala> Read.valueOrNone[Int]("100")
res0: Option[Int] = Some(100)

scala> Read.valueOrNone[String]("100")
res1: Option[String] = Some(100)
```

This is very similar to requiring an implicit conversion implicitly, but it has the advantage of not requiring you to pollute your implicit scope with conversions that could be applied in places you don't expect.

Comment: I agree that type classes are a cleaner (and better) solution than implicit conversions, but it seemed like an overkill for this particular question. BTW you and I seem to be bumping into each other quite often lately :) (well, in the Scala tag). You seem to know a lot about type-classes. If you could read my blog post on type-classes and let me know what you think, it would be a valuable feedback for me. https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/ad-hoc-polymorphism-and-type-classes-442ae22e5342